# Is there a way to define a skew_symmetric variable in cvxpy?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, cvxpy

I want to define a 'skew_symmetric' variable in cvxpy, with real elements. Is there a short way to do this? The package supports defining 'symmetric' variables but not 'skew_symmetric' variables.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to declare 'skew_symmetric' variable. But you can easily enforce it with a relevant constraint over the variable.

A matrix is skew symmetric if A^T = -A, so you can add it as a constraint:

```py
skew_constraint = [A.T == -A]
```